# Formal argument "axes" matched by multiple actual arguments

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am trying to follow the instructions from this website : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bivariate/vignettes/bivariate.pdf (page 14)

To replicate the above styles of plots.
[image]

I tried to make my own data for this:

e.g.

```
a = rnorm(100,100,100)
b = rnorm(100,100,100)
c = rnorm(100,100,100)
d = data.frame(a,b,c)

 plot (d, theme="blue",
        axes = c (TRUE, FALSE), xat = c (-1.5, 1.5) )
```

But this produces the following error:

```
Error in plot.default(...) : 
  formal argument "axes" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

I tried removing one of the variables:

```
d$c = NULL

 plot (d, theme="blue",
            axes = c (TRUE, FALSE), xat = c (-1.5, 1.5) )
```

But this produces a different graph:

[image]

Can someone please tell me why my visualizations are not looking like the ones from the tutorial?

EDIT:

I also tried the following code:

```
plot.BV(d, theme="blue",
      axes = c (TRUE, FALSE), xat = c (-1.5, 1.5) )
```

But I got the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("bv.plotf") : 
  no applicable method for 'bv.plotf' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
```

Comment: Have you loaded the bivariate package?

Comment: Yes, I have it loaded

Comment: @heds1: can you please try running this on your computer?